# The "PushSubscription" object differs in the documentation

Tags: javascript, push-notification, web-push

I'm trying to implement a push notification system on my site, and the documentation says that I need to store the `PushSubscription` object returned by the `PushManager.subscribe` method in the database.

The problem is that in the documentation the `PushSubscription` object does not have an `auth` property (as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushSubscription)), but when I `console.log` the object returned by the `PushManager.subscribe` method, it does have that field.

Something like this:

```json
{
  "endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/cg6PtxFx...",
  "expirationTime":null,
  "keys":{
    "p256dh":"BKvv8i80Eqai6TnPhviquFhrKDdvHXPWkPWNjLtVuE7oxt...",
    "auth":"BX2FxMZMAk0VUivVlxWRzw"
  }
}
```

Where can I find more info about the `keys` field of the `PushSubscription` object?